# How to convert ValueCollection to Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I've a dictionary member of type `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<SomeType>>>`. What I want is to get nested dictionary from this i.e. `Dictionary<string, List<SomeType>>`. I thought I'd get this using `myDict.Values`, but that's actually returning `ValueCollection` and not the nested-dictionary itself.

Now I'm trying to get this done using ValueCollection.ToDictionary function, but please share if you've already done something similar.

**Update**
I want to return nested-dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, List<SomeType>> GetKeyPairValues()
{
  // get nested dictionary from this.myDict
}
```

Comment: what is expected result when you have one more than Dictionary<string, List<SomeType>> in current Dictionary?

Comment: I'd like to merge them. In my case it is sure that Key value of the one nested dictionary will not conflict with other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `GroupBy` to group by `Key` then merge all list with the same key:

```
 Dictionary<string, List<SomeType>> GetKeyPairValues()
 {
      return dic.Values.SelectMany(d => d)
                       .GroupBy(p => p.Key)
                       .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, 
                                     g => g.SelectMany(pair => pair.Value)
                                           .ToList());
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

> What I want is to get nested dictionary

```
return myDict.Values.ToDictionary(x => x.Keys, x => x.Values);
```

Based on your comment, and looking at how complex the LINQ expression is going to have to be for this, why not just go for a basic for loop e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, List<SomeType>> GetKeyPairValues()
{
    foreach (var pair in dict)
    { 
        yield return pair.Value;
    }
}
```

It also might be more efficient than using LINQ.

Comment: I did this in my first attempt to use ToDictionary, but ToDictionary(x => x.Keys, x => x.Values) is actually creating Dictionary of <KeyCollection, ValueCollection>

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<int>>>();//initialize your source dictionary
var mergedDictionary = dictionary.SelectMany(d => d.Value).ToDictionary(k=>k.Key, k=>k.Value);
```

Update: use ToDictionary

Comment: I think output of SelectMany would be IEnumerable and not the dictionary.

Comment: @AksharRoop it will, this isn't what your looking for.

Comment: I want Dictionary<string, List<SomeType>> to hide some details how things are implemented.

Comment: @AksharRoop see my answer for how the get that

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Dictionary<>` implements multiple `Values` properties. If you use it through `IDictionary<>` you get a `ICollection<TValue>`

```
IDictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<SomeType>>> dict = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<SomeType>>>();
ICollection<Dictionary<string, List<SomeType>>> = dict.Values;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was actually looking for geting Dictionary type and not the ICollection.

Comment: but Values gives you all the Dictionaries in the Dictionary, hence a collection